# How to efficiently check if a word's all letters are the same in C++

Tags: c++, string, performance

I have checked and couldn't a better option by checking the word's letters one by one. I've decided to use the ascii equivalence of the letter check by diving the word but didn't lead to any where as well. Any Ideas?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you are asking.  Could you maybe try to rephrase it more carefully?

Comment: Is this for school?  Take the first letter.  Is it the same as the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc.  You don't want to loop?  Why not?  Why be fancy if simple will get the job done?

Comment: I'm affraid linear search is the best that can be done.

Comment: It is not for school. I am planning to use it in an algorithm question and there are many easy ways to find the solution. I regard the efficiency of the solution. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You could perhaps check the character code and then shift and add several times to get a sequence which would allow you to do a bitwise AND with chunks of the original array cast to integers. A lot more complicated to get right, but potentially faster for long strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <string>

bool are_all_characters_the_same(const std::string &s) {
    return (s.size() == 0) || s.find_first_not_of(s[0]) == std::string::npos;
}
```

Clearly in the worst case it can't be done without examining every character. Whichever character(s) you don't examine, might be the same as the others or different, and the result needs to be sensitive to that in the case where the ones you do examine are all the same.

If you know something about what might be in the string, then the order in which you examine the characters might affect how early you can bail out. But knowing nothing, you may as well read them in order, and reading them in order might result in better cache performance.

Things get more complicated if the string is long enough that it's worth parallelizing.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever algorithm may be, you'll have to go through all the letters, there's nothing much you can do to avoid it.

Comment: Worst case, yes. However, you can stop checking earlier for "abaaa";

Comment: @Johnsyweb no, if you want to ensure that all the letters are the same - you **have** to check all of them in order to answer **yes**.

Comment: Yes. Worst case is success :-)

Answer (score 0):

You will at least have to do `n-1` comparisons, where `n` is the length of the string.  The most naive approach is going to be (in pseudo code):

```
c = first character
for i in second character to last character:
    if c = i then continue else return false
return true
```

Comment: Would it be possible to apply a divide and conquer approach, diving the word's letters recursively and having the case if any different letter is seen return false ?

Comment: @rolandbishop that would be O(n) time with a bigger (worse) constant.

Comment: No, it's not going to help.  You'll still end up doing *at least* the same number of comparisons, as the recursion won't terminate until you've done all `n-1` comparisons.

Comment: @Gian you are right. Guess I will implement it with a linear search. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: @rolandbishop: You have to look at every character anyway, so a simple linear scan does the least amount of work possible. It's also the most cache-friendly and probably fastest method.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the solution to this problem can be optimized for large strings, I don't believe it is n-p complete, because a CPU can examine two values that are larger than 8 bits in a single instruction.
For example, the string 'aaaaaaaa' in hex is 61616161 61616161 which is (if I've got my endianess correct) 1633771873 1633771873 as integer.

My memory of assembler is fading fast, but comparing two 32bit integers on a 32bit processor is two instructions: mv and cp (mov cmp?), but comparing eight 8 bit integers is 16 instructions (mv cp, mv cp, etc). (Feel free to correct me if I am wrong).

This optimization obviously only works on strings that are multiples of the CPUs word size. If the word size is 32 bits and the string size is more than 8 characters long, then algorithm can be done in (n/4) + (n%4) steps. With a 64 bit word size it would be (n/8) + (n%8) steps, assuming the string is more than 16 characters long.